# How to update screen when instance of external stateful widget class is updated

Tags: flutter

I am displaying the weight of an instance of a person class on my homepage. When I update the weight of this instance through a form in a popup bottom sheet the displayed weight is only changed after a hot reload. How can I trigger a setState in my person class when its instances parameters are changed in homepage?

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:metricwidget/screens/homepage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  // Root of application
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
      
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Homepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

person.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class person extends StatefulWidget {
  int? weight;
  person({Key? key, this.weight}) : super(key: key);

  void updateWeight(newWeight){
    weight = newWeight;
  }

  @override
  _personState createState() => _personState();
}

class _personState extends State<person> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        widget.weight.toString(),
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

homepage.dart

```
import 'package:mvs/person.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  var joe = person(weight: 23);
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: joe,
          ),
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            onSaved: (String? value) {
                              if (int.parse(value!) > 0) {
                                setState(() {
                                  joe.updateWeight(int.parse(value));
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            maxLength: 3,
                            initialValue: joe.weight.toString(),
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.label),
                            ),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return "Please enter value";
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: const Text("submit"),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            child: const Text("Update"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `provider` package since it allows you to access the variable globally and notifies listeners when it changes

Comment: Is there a way to use a provider with multiple instances of a class?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple instances of class?

Comment: Initially, I tried creating a parent class with a change notifier and had it's children be extensions or multiple instances (for if I wanted multiple people like Joe, Bob, etc). Unfortunately, I couldn't get this working BUT was able to create it using three separate classes each with its own change notifier.  This seems to align with the Flutter docs as well so it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this using provider and changenotifier, same as the format outlined in the docs below

Reference: https://pub.dev/packages/provider